# Is my POJO object for firebase Realtime Database built correctly?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, model, pojo

I am trying to build POJO for my firebase RealTime Database.
Am i doing it correctly according to my Realtime Database? Link below

detailData,detailContent,detailTitleContent,isDetail,titleContent they named the same everywhere,they just have different text in them.

```
public class POJO {
 private String titleContent;
 private String detailContent;
 private String detailTitleContent;
 private List<String> detailData = new ArrayList<>();
 private List<String> textInfo = new ArrayList<>();
 private boolean isDetail;
 private boolean isList;

public POJO() {

}


public POJO(String titleContent, String detailContent, String 
   detailTitleContent, List<String> detailData, List<String> textInfo, 
  boolean isDetail, boolean isList) {
    this.titleContent = titleContent;
    this.detailContent = detailContent;
    this.detailTitleContent = detailTitleContent;
    this.detailData = detailData;
    this.textInfo = textInfo;
    this.isDetail = isDetail;
    this.isList = isList;
}



public String getTitleContent() {
    return titleContent;
}

public String getDetailContent() {
    return detailContent;
}

public String getDetailTitleContent() {
    return detailTitleContent;
}

public List<String> getDetailData() {
    return detailData;
}

public List<String> getTextInfo() {
    return textInfo;
}

public boolean isDetail() {
    return isDetail;
}

public boolean isList() {
    return isList;
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is to get us to review your POJO Class/es? You can simply use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate your POJO...

Comment: nope,question whether it is right according to my database. My json i way too big for it

Comment: "whether it is right" that is what reviewing means... as I've stated before, manually writing the POJO class/es is okay but you must be careful with any typos. But as to your initial question, your POJO is incorrect because you've stored everything in 1 class. Each distinct object should have it's own class. Please provide the JSON for this schema and I'll assist you further.

Comment: Here is the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0VC1iU1jAGj_bNRY56-dXKfzPq0hcT7 . Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the following response (which you've provided), I'll be creating the POJO Classes

```
{
    "datas": [{
        "detailData": [{
            "detailContent": "<p>LOTS of information</p>",
            "detailTitleContent": "Title"
        }, {
            "detailContent": "<p>Lots of more information!</p>",
            "detailTitleContent": "Second Title"
        }],
        "isDetail": false,
        "titleContent": "Last Title"
    }]
}
```

Therefore, looking at this response, you can see that your first (Let's name is "MyPojo") class will have an array of "datas" object.

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private Datas[] datas;

    public Datas[] getDatas (){
        return datas;
    }

    public void setDatas (Datas[] datas){
        this.datas = datas;
    }
}
```

Now we have to make a model object for the "Datas":

```
public class Datas
{
    private String isDetail;
    private String titleContent;
    private DetailData[] detailData;

    public String getIsDetail (){
        return isDetail;
    }

    public void setIsDetail (String isDetail){
        this.isDetail = isDetail;
    }

    public String getTitleContent (){
        return titleContent;
    }

    public void setTitleContent (String titleContent){
        this.titleContent = titleContent;
    }

    public DetailData[] getDetailData (){
        return detailData;
    }

    public void setDetailData (DetailData[] detailData){
        this.detailData = detailData;
    }
}
```

Last but not least, "DetailData" model which is another array:

```
public class DetailData
{
    private String detailTitleContent;
    private String detailContent;

    public String getDetailTitleContent (){
        return detailTitleContent;
    }

    public void setDetailTitleContent (String detailTitleContent){
        this.detailTitleContent = detailTitleContent;
    }

    public String getDetailContent (){
        return detailContent;
    }

    public void setDetailContent (String detailContent){
        this.detailContent = detailContent;
    }
}
```

From here, you should have a complete Pojo for your JSON response and ready to be handled. Just want to point 2 things out for your benefit: 
**1.** I highly recommend you reading the following tutorial [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and pay close attention to the **The difference between [ and { – (Square brackets and Curly brackets)** section as you want to gain in-depth understanding of **JSONArray** and **JSONObject**.
**2.** Use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON response as it's helpful sometimes and also use [Convert XML or JSON to Java Pojo Classes - Online](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) tool to generate the Pojo classes based on the JSON response (I used it myself in this case). The major benefit behind this is accuracy, takes less than 1 minute to copy and implement.
Good luck and let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help !